# Starting wildfly 9 with eclipselink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, wildfly

I just switched from glassfish to wildfly 9 and I would like to use Eclipselink since it is what I was using before. I added the eclipselink.jar in the `C:\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\eclipse\persistence\main` folder. And did the following

added to module.xml :

```
    <resource-root path="eclipselink.jar">
    <filter>
            <exclude path="javax/**" />
    </filter>
```

in persistence.xml :

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

error :

```
16:53:17,021 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) Failed to define class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.JPARSExceptionMapper in Module "org.eclipse.persistence:main" from local module loader @45283ce2 (finder: local module finder @2077d4de (roots: C:\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\modules,C:\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\modules\system\layers\base)): java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/rs/exceptions/JPARSExceptionMapper (Module "org.eclipse.persistence:main" from local module loader @45283ce2 (finder: local module finder @2077d4de (roots: C:\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\modules,C:\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\modules\system\layers\base)))
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:437)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:269)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:77)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:560)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication.<init>(JPARSApplication.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:148)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2211)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:295)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:236)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:112)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:230)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:511)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:353)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:432)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper from [Module "org.eclipse.persistence:main" from local module loader @45283ce2 (finder: local module finder @2077d4de (roots: C:\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\modules,C:\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
    ... 37 more

16:53:17,022 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./csbasement: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./csbasement: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct public org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication()
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct public org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication()
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:160)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2211)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:295)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:236)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:112)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:230)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:511)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/rs/exceptions/JPARSExceptionMapper (Module "org.eclipse.persistence:main" from local module loader @45283ce2 (finder: local module finder @2077d4de (roots: C:\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\modules,C:\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\modules\system\layers\base)))
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:437)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:269)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:77)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:560)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication.<init>(JPARSApplication.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:148)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:353)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:432)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper from [Module "org.eclipse.persistence:main" from local module loader @45283ce2 (finder: local module finder @2077d4de (roots: C:\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\modules,C:\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
    ... 37 more

16:53:17,031 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "csbasement.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./csbasement" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./csbasement: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct public org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication()
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct public org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication()
    Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/rs/exceptions/JPARSExceptionMapper (Module \"org.eclipse.persistence:main\" from local module loader @45283ce2 (finder: local module finder @2077d4de (roots: C:\\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\\modules,C:\\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\\modules\\system\\layers\\base)))
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I added

```
<module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
```

in the module.xml and everything is now smooth.